# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function error while running the built project

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react project and built it with `npm run build`. When I view this app on my browser with npm start, everything is fine. But When I try to serve this react app from my backend written in nodejs , I get this error in my console:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at L (App.js:34)
at ia (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
at Ws (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
at Sl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at xl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at El (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
at ml (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
at dl (react-dom.production.min.js:237)
at Gl (react-dom.production.min.js:285)
at react-dom.production.min.js:289
```

The line at App.js:34 is-> `const [hasnewreqs,sethasnewreqs]=useState("")`

My project structure is as follows:

- 1 Test folder

  - 2 Backend server folder (nodejs)

    - 3 React app folder (lconnect)

      - 4 build

        - 5 index.html

This is what I am using to server the react app:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==="production"){
app.use(express.static(path.join(_dirname1,"/lconnect/build")));
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
res.sendFile(path.resolve(_dirname1,"lconnect","build","index.html"))
})
}
```

This is the full App.js file:

```
     function App() {
     const [hasnewreqs,sethasnewreqs]=useState("")
     const [mentionedposts,setmentionedposts]=useState("")
     const[uschats,setuschats]=useState(0)

      useEffect(()=>{
      if(localStorage.getItem("a")){
      fetch(`/pchats/${localStorage.getItem("a")}`)
     .then(res=>res.json())
     .then(result=>{
      setuschats(result.pm.length)
  
     })
     }
   },[])
    useEffect(()=>{
    if(localStorage.getItem("a"))
    fetch('/getreqs',{
        method:"PUT",
        headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
     },
     body:JSON.stringify({
     i:localStorage.getItem("a"),
     pass:localStorage.getItem("b")
    })
   })
 .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(result=>{
    if(result.message==="yes"){ 
      sethasnewreqs("yes")
      }

     })
  },[])

 useEffect(()=>{

if(localStorage.getItem("a"))
fetch('/getmentions',{
  method:"PUT",
  headers:{
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
  },
  body:JSON.stringify({
     i:localStorage.getItem("a"),
     pass:localStorage.getItem("b")
  })
  })
 .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(result=>{
    if(result.posts.length>0){
      setmentionedposts("yes")
   
       }

    })
     },[])
     const Rountingfunc=()=>{
    if(!localStorage.getItem("a") && !localStorage.getItem("b")){
     return(
   <Switch>
   <Route path ="/signup">
    <Signup/>
    </Route> 
     <Route path ="/login">
      <Login/>
      </Route>  
    <Route exact path="/">
     <Welcome/>
    </Route>
    </Switch>

      )
       }
  else{
    return(
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path ="/profile">
       <Userpage/>
        </Route> 
      <Route path ="/editprofile/:id">
        <Login/>
      </Route>  
      <Route path ="/createpost">
  <Createpost/>
</Route> 
<Route path ="/explore">
  <Homepage/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/profile/:username">
  <Viewprofile/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/post/:pid">
  <Fullpost/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/messages">
  <Userstomesaage/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/message/:uid">
  <Messageuser/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/friendreqs">
  <Friendrequests/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/home">
  <Friendsposts/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/recommended">
  <Recommended/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/guidelines">
  <Guidelines/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/likes/:postid">
  <Likespage/>
</Route>  

<Route path ="/dislikes/:postid">
  <Dislikespage/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/mentions">
  <Mentions/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/users">
  <Allusers/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/about">
  <About/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/more">
  <Mobilemore/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/privacypolicy">
  <Privacypolicy/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/">
  <Privacypolicy/>
</Route>  
<Route path ="/notifications">
  <Mobilenots reqs={hasnewreqs} mentions={mentionedposts}/>
</Route>  
        </Switch>
    )
  }
  }
   return (
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Navigbar reqs={hasnewreqs} mentions={mentionedposts} nmsgs=                        
      {uschats}/>
       <Rountingfunc/>
       </BrowserRouter>
    );
   }
```

Comment: Can you please provide further explanation and code snippets?

Comment: @Chaka15
Sir,should  I put something else?

Comment: Could you post a file with `const [hasnewreqs,sethasnewreqs]=useState("")` inside it?

Comment: @Chaka15 did it

Comment: Do you get any warnings in the console tab when you run in dev mode by `npm start`?

Comment: @Prajwal Kulkarni  no